# Contraction mapping from PMA Rudin

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f$ is real function on $(-\infty,\infty)$. Call $x$ a *fixed point* of $f$ if $f(x)=x$.

a) However, if there is a constant $A<1$ such that $|f'(t)|\leqslant A$ for all real $t$, prove that a fixed point $x$ of $f$ exists, and that $x=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} x_n$, where $x_1$ is an arbitrary real number and $$x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$$ for $n=1,2,3,\dots$

b) Show that the procees described in a) can be visualized by zig-zag path $$(x_1,x_2)\to(x_2,x_2)\to(x_2,x_3)\to(x_3,x_3)\to(x_3,x_4)\to\cdots.$$

Part a) is not difficult and I solved it without any problems. But I don't know what means part b) and can anyone explain me the solution of this part?

I would be very grateful.

Comment: Its a numerical process for finding the fixed point. Search for any iterative process for finding fixed point

Comment: you may want to google "cobweb plot": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobweb_plot .

here is an interesting webpage: http://mathinsight.org/cobwebbing_graphical_solution

Comment: @el.Salvador, Thank you! But how to show a) can be visualized by above zig-zag path? I can't understand that